# gRPC: Failed to parse binary descriptor

Tags: php, laravel, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've been following this tutorial: https://tsh.io/blog/grpc-php/

I have everything imported, however Im getting failed to parse binary descriptor in this file.

`        $pool = \Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool::getGeneratedPool();

```
    if (static::$is_initialized == true) {
        return;
    }

    \GPBMetadata\Google\Protobuf\GPBEmpty::initOnce();

    $pool->internalAddGeneratedFile(
        '
    �
    bookstore.protoendpoints.examples.bookstore""
    Shelf

    id (
    theme ( "1
    Book

    id (
    author (    
    title ( "K
    ListShelvesResponse4
    shelves (2#.endpoints.examples.bookstore.Shelf"H
    CreateShelfRequest2
    shelf (2#.endpoints.examples.bookstore.Shelf" 
    GetShelfRequest
    shelf ("#
    DeleteShelfRequest
    shelf ("!
    ListBooksRequest
    shelf ("F
    ListBooksResponse1
    books (2".endpoints.examples.bookstore.Book"T
    CreateBookRequest
    shelf (0
    book (2".endpoints.examples.bookstore.Book"-
    GetBookRequest
    shelf (
    book ("0
    DeleteBookRequest
    shelf (
    book (2�
        BookstoreZ
    ListShelves.google.protobuf.Empty1.endpoints.examples.bookstore.ListShelvesResponse"f
    CreateShelf0.endpoints.examples.bookstore.CreateShelfRequest#.endpoints.examples.bookstore.Shelf"`
    GetShelf-.endpoints.examples.bookstore.GetShelfRequest#.endpoints.examples.bookstore.Shelf"Y
    DeleteShelf0.endpoints.examples.bookstore.DeleteShelfRequest.google.protobuf.Empty"n
        ListBooks..endpoints.examples.bookstore.ListBooksRequest/.endpoints.examples.bookstore.ListBooksResponse"c

    CreateBook/.endpoints.examples.bookstore.CreateBookRequest".endpoints.examples.bookstore.Book"]
    GetBook,.endpoints.examples.bookstore.GetBookRequest".endpoints.examples.bookstore.Book"W

    DeleteBook/.endpoints.examples.bookstore.DeleteBookRequest.google.protobuf.Empty"B;
    \'com.google.endpoints.examples.bookstoreBBookstoreProtoPbproto3',
        true
    );`
```

Googles suggestions have not helped. Im using this implemented into a laravel project with php8.1.

The code inside the internalAddGeneratedFile function was already there upon implementing the package.

Tried following the guide, followed many possible solutions on the interwebs to no avail.

Just trying to run a basic call to return all books.